# wxPython: My toolbar does't show buttons in Windows

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I did a small application and it works nice in linux. But, I get some problems with the toolbar in Windows 7.
The toolbar has some buttons which Windows doesn't show (But, there are in Linux). I am using Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8.

I don't know what I am missing.

Regards,
Cristian.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher
from excel import excelmaker
from model import Model
from ObjectListView import ColumnDefn, ObjectListView
import utils
import threading

wildcard = "Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|" \
        "All files (*.*)|*.*"

class ApplicationGui(wx.App):

    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)

    def OnInit(self):
        # create frame here
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show()
        return True

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.exportText=''

        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        self.objectListView = ObjectListView(self, wx.ID_ANY,style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.objectListView.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK
        self.objectListView.SetObjects([Model()])

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.create_toolbar(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Add(self.progress, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainSizer.Add(self.objectListView, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    def create_toolbar(self,sizer):
        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self)

        loadBtn = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Cargar Excel', wx.Bitmap('resources/open.png'), shortHelp='Cargar Excel')
        pasteBtn = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Pegar', wx.Bitmap('resources/paste.png'), shortHelp='Pegar Columnas')
        cleanBtn = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Borrar', wx.Bitmap('resources/clean.png'), shortHelp='Borrar tabla')
        toolbar.AddSeparator()
        addBtn = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Agregar', wx.Bitmap('resources/add.png'), shortHelp='Agregar fila')

        toolbar.AddSeparator()
        self.exportText = wx.TextCtrl(toolbar, -1, size=(140,-1))
        self.exportText.SetValue('output.xlsx')
        toolbar.AddControl(self.exportText)
        exportBtn = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Exportar', wx.Bitmap('resources/export.png'), shortHelp='Generar Excel')

        toolbar.AddSeparator()
        about = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'Acerca', wx.Bitmap('resources/about.png'), shortHelp='Ayuda')


        randomId = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onPaste, id=randomId)
        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('V'), randomId )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

        sizer.Add(toolbar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onOpenFile, loadBtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onPaste, pasteBtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onClean, cleanBtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onExport, exportBtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onAddRow, addBtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onAbout, about)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY,
                      title="Exceltronic", size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the call

```
toolbar.Realize()
```

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToolBar.html?highlight=toolbar#ToolBar.Realize